# Howto serve a second subdomain through Apache Proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, subdomain

I have an Apache frontend server, that until today proxies traffic for a subdomain `api.myapp.net` to a backend server running a Rails app on an Nginx.

Now I added a second subdomain `alpha.myapp.net` in my domain portfolio and gave it the same IP. Traffic to that subdomain shall not hit the Rails application, but a second VHost on the Nginx server that is setup to serve a static site.

So I have a proxy config for `api.myapp.net`:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@myapp.net
    ServerName api.myapp.net
    ServerAlias api.myapp.net

    DirectoryIndex index.html

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteLog /var/log/apache2/rewrite.log
    RewriteLogLevel 9

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(api\.)?myapp\.net$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myapp.net$1 [L,R=301]

    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.145/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.145/

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
```

And I setup a second config for `alpha.myapp.net`:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@myapp.net
    ServerName alpha.myapp.net
    ServerAlias alpha.myapp.net

    DirectoryIndex index.html

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteLog /var/log/apache2/rewrite.log
    RewriteLogLevel 9

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(alpha\.)?myapp\.net$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myapp.net$1 [L,R=301]

    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.145/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.145/

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
```

What happens now, is, that all traffic to `alpha.myapp.net` hits my Rails application that listens for requests for `api.myapp.net`.

I sorted out all Nginx config problems, so I thought it must be an Apache misconfiguration. What I see in Apache's rewrite log seems to explain the problem:

```
xxx.yyy.zzz.95 - - [08/Apr/2013:09:34:35 +0200] [alpha.myapp.net/sid#b9279870][rid#b9311d38/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.html
xxx.yyy.zzz.95 - - [08/Apr/2013:09:34:35 +0200] [alpha.myapp.net/sid#b9279870][rid#b9311d38/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/index.html'
xxx.yyy.zzz.95 - - [08/Apr/2013:09:34:35 +0200] [alpha.myapp.net/sid#b9279870][rid#b9311d38/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='alpha.myapp.net' pattern='!^(alpha\.)?myapp\.net$' => not-matched
xxx.yyy.zzz.95 - - [08/Apr/2013:09:34:35 +0200] [alpha.myapp.net/sid#b9279870][rid#b9311d38/initial] (1) pass through /index.html
```

The last part `pass through /index.html` seems to omit the subdomain and domain part. So the Nginx backend server does not now, which subdomain is requested, ans serves the request from the first available server, which ist `api`.

The question now seems to be: How can I proxy the traffic from Apache frontend to Nginx backend and maintain the subdomain and domain?

Or could there be another problem?

Hope someone can help.

Regards Felix

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the answer comes along with the question. The problem was exactly the missing hostname.

I solved the problem by editing `/etc/hosts` on my Apache server and adding two entries. One `api.myapp.net`, one `alpha.myapp.net` both referencing the same IP.

Then I changed bot Apache proxy configurations, so that `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` do not use IP's anymore but the new hostnames.

And voila it works.